# Sketching the circle for the equation: $\sqrt{(x -1)^2 + (y-1)^2} = \sqrt{2}$

Tags: analytic-geometry

How should I sketch the circle for the equation mentioned in the title? If I calculate the square root of the number $2$ it continues to infinity.

$\sqrt2 = 1.414213562...$

Comment: try raising both sides of the equation to the power of 2.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Nevertheless, it is impossible to draw a circle with radius equal to square root of 2.

Comment: It is impossible to draw any circle. But you can draw a very good approximation.

Comment: I'm afraid whether the question is sketching $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @Inceptio The real notation of the equation was: Draw the circle for the problem $(x -1)^2 + (y -1)^2 = 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\sqrt 2$ is construtible. The distance between (0,0) and (1,1) is $\sqrt 2$.

Draw a circle centering at (1,1) with (0,0) on it.